# How to slow down rotation when the rotation at the end, like a wheel of fortune

Tags: javascript

I am making a wheel of fortune or roulette. Everything works well, just the spinning part, I want the spin to slow down near the end of the spin. where should I change or add in my script?

```
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max)
  let rotations = 360 * ((Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)) + 20) + ((index - 1) / this.max * 360) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (360/this.max)))
  // let rotations = ((index - 1) / this.max * 360)
  let seconds = 2 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2)
  console.log(rotations)
  console.log(index)
  console.log(this.prizes[index])
  const randomAnswer = this.prizes[index]
```

How to slow down rotation when the rotation at the end, like a wheel of fortune

Comment: This is javascript, not java, please edit your question and remove the tag.

Comment: To provide a comprehensive answer, you should demonstrate a reproducible example. With the current snippet, nothing can be done, as you copied only a fragment of the code. I assume it includes HTML, CSS, and additional JS code.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of a complete example, **I quickly reconstructed a spinning wheel**. In the example, you will find the **HTML and CSS codes** as well. In the spinning functions, **I need to reference the elements to create the demo**.

I created the wheel by dividing the `.circle` class into 8 equal triangles using the `conic-gradient` applied to the background. **I placed 8 `span` elements inside the `.circle` div, labeled with numbers**. Based on the number, **I can set the exact position in the `.circle span` CSS reference and rotate the value so that it faces towards the center of the circle** (so the value of the winning span will always be readable).

**I placed a downward pointing arrow above the circle**. This arrow will play an important role in determining the winning element.

**We will use the `spin` function to spin the wheel**, which can be triggered by the `button`. **I also added an input field where you can specify the duration of the spin in seconds**.

In the `spin` function, **I establish a random starting point, and then I rotate the circle for the specified duration**. By manipulating the CSS, **I can control the speed and time of the rotation**, so it won't spin at a constant rate. **I always set the duration in the `transition` (default is 10 seconds) and the calculated random rotation (default is at least 1440 degrees, equivalent to 4 full spins)**.

**After that, using `setTimeout`, I stop the rotation after the number of seconds specified in the input field**. Then **I determine which `span` element is closest to the triangle, so we get the winning element and can display its value**.

```js
// Function to get a random rotation between 0 and 360 degrees
function getRandomRotation() {
  return Math.random() * 360;
}

// Function to handle the spinning animation
function spin() {
  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  const duration = parseFloat(document.getElementById('seconds').value);
  const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
  const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');

  const randomRotation = getRandomRotation();

  button.disabled = 'disabled';

  circle.style.transition = 'transform 0s';
  circle.style.transform = `rotate(${randomRotation}deg)`;

  void circle.offsetWidth;

  circle.style.transition = `transform ${duration}s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)`;
  circle.style.transform = `rotate(${randomRotation + 1440}deg)`; // 4 full spins (1440 degrees)

  setTimeout(() => {
    circle.style.transition = '';
    const currentRotation = randomRotation + 1440;
    circle.style.transform = `rotate(${currentRotation}deg)`;
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');

    // Calculate the closest number to the arrow's rotation
    const spans = circle.querySelectorAll('span');
    const arrowRotation = -arrow.getBoundingClientRect().top + currentRotation;
    let minDifference = Infinity;
    let closestNumber;

    spans.forEach((span) => {
      const spanRotation = -span.getBoundingClientRect().top + currentRotation;
      const difference = Math.abs(spanRotation - arrowRotation);
      if (difference < minDifference) {
        minDifference = difference;
        closestNumber = span.textContent;
      }
    });

    console.log('Closest number:', closestNumber);
  }, duration * 1000);
}
```

```css
.spin-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(from -22.5deg, #4ab2e5 0, #4ab2e5 12.5%, #001b66 12.5%, #001b66 25%, #4ab2e5 25%, #4ab2e5 37.5%, #001b66 37.5%, #001b66 50%, #4ab2e5 50%, #4ab2e5 62.5%, #001b66 62.5%, #001b66 75%, #4ab2e5 75%, #4ab2e5 87.5%, #001b66 87.5%, #001b66 100%);
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(45deg * var(--n))) translate(80px) rotate(90deg);
}

.circle span:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #4ab2e5;
}

.circle span:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #001b66;
}

.arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

.prize {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin-container">
  <div class="prize">Prize</div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>

  <div class="circle">
    <span style="--n: 0;">1</span>
    <span style="--n: 1;">2</span>
    <span style="--n: 2;">3</span>
    <span style="--n: 3;">4</span>
    <span style="--n: 4;">5</span>
    <span style="--n: 5;">6</span>
    <span style="--n: 6;">7</span>
    <span style="--n: 7;">8</span>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="number" id="seconds" value="10">
<button onclick="spin()">SPIN</button>
```